# Liskov Substitution Principle and class design for a game

Tags: c++, oop, solid-principles

In my game I have defined a `Screen` class, that contains references to a number of visual `Entity` objects, that may be drawn to the display:

```
class Screen {
public:

private:
  std::vector<Entity*> entities_;
};
```

All `Entity`'s, have a `Draw()` function:

```
class Entity {
  public:
    void Draw();
  private:
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
};
```

The `Screen` is responsible for invoking the `Draw()` function on each of its `Entity`s.

The problem is that some (but not all) `Entity`'s also need to be updateable, i.e. over time they will change their appearance/position. The `Screen` also needs to invoke an `Update()` function *but only for those objects that are Updateable*.

My question is:

Does it make sense to derive a class from `Entity` that has an Update function:

```
class ChangingEntity : public Entity {
  public: 
     void Update(int time);
};
```

and have `Screen` look like this:

```
class Screen {
public:

private:
  std::vector<Entity*> entities_;
  std::vector<ChangingEntity*> changing_entities_;
};
```

If I do the above, then I invoke only `Draw()` for each of the `Entity`s, and `Draw()` and `Update()` on each of the `ChangingEntity`s.

Or - should I just put the `Update()` function in `Entity`, and if an `Entity` object can't update, then `Update()` has no implementation?

Comment: If you know how to keep the two apart statically, then make to separate containers. Polymorphism is for when you *don't* know statically which type you're going to use.

Comment: How do you mean "If you know how to keep the two apart statically"...do you mean if I can explicitly separate them, and know beforehand what type they are? If so, then yes I can do that.

Comment: "Does it make sense to derive a class from Entity" -- probably not at the moment, because `Entity` is not well-designed for use as a base class. It has a public non-virtual destructor, which is bad news. For a base class the destructor should be either virtual or protected.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things you can enhance here;

It's better not to make the entity draw itself, use a separate `Draw()` function or Drawable class ([Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). In your current approach you are making any class that needs drawing to extend Entity, next time you will figure out that a class doesn't need to be an entity to be drawable. So use a separate draw function .

Second you should define what an Entity is, Ogre3D for example define the [Entity](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/classOgre_1_1Entity.html) as `an instance of a discrete, movable object based on a Mesh`, I don't see that your current definition is sufficient, it only contains position and a draw function. You can define an entity as an Updatable object, and another class called `StaticEntity` no need for polymorphism. And let the Scene have two separate lists and actually be able to update the objects, again separate the renderer from the scene.

Third your `Screen` class should be called `Renderer` and have objects that can be rendered registered based on their static type. You can also have a Drawable interface.